# Why is action customize_register being done twice?

Tags: theme-customizer

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wdwt_customizer_register' );
function wdwt_customizer_register(){
  add_action( 'customize_register', 'wdwt_customizer_add_panels' );
}
function wdwt_customizer_add_panels($wp_customize ){
  /*this function is called twice*/
}
```

The same is also true for twentyfifteen theme. `twentyfifteen_customize_register` function hooked on the same tag, is called twice.

It seems that the action 'customize_register' is being done twice, once in customizer admin, and once in preview part.
WordPress version is 4.3.

Is this bug or a feature ?

Comment: This `wdwt_customizer_register()` function is not part of the WordPress core, so I assume it ships with your theme.

Comment: Yes, this is theme code. But why `customize_register` action hook is called twice? All this code is just included in theme and is loaded unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

I think the customizer creates an xhr request for to load the site preview( see devtools under the network > xhr tab ). In my case I want to check if a certain variable isset via the $_GET['foo'] variable. My function must be called once and not twice otherwise it will override my previous state.

My solution is to check if the $_POST['wp_customize'] it's empty or not. If empty that means that my function doesn't get called twice by preview request.

I use the following hook/action [customize_loaded_components](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_loaded_components/)

Example:

```
function wpdocs_remove_widgets_panel( $components ) {
    if( empty( $_POST['wp_customize'] ) ) {
       // Do stuff here that will not be loaded twice by the previewer
    }
    return $components;
}

add_filter( 'customize_loaded_components', 'wpdocs_remove_widgets_panel' );
```